# Resistor for NPN Transistor

Tags: transistors

[image]

How can I find the value of resistor for R1 and R2? The hfe for this transistor is 120. Where should I start?

Comment: Hello and welcome! What function is the circuit supposed to perform? What are the LED ratings, how bright should they be?  I suspect R1 is wired to the wrong side (GND instead of +V).

Comment: The led rating is about 1.2 to 3.6 V for Vf and 10 to 30 mA for current rating. Just noticed my wrong connection. Thanks for mention.

Comment: R1 is still wired incorrectly

Comment: You still haven't told us what your circuit is intended to do.

Comment: Eh, if there was someone to flip horizontally Q1... For the umpteenth time, I am convinced how important the way a scheme is drawn is.

Comment: Math and Tim - R1 is located correctly.  The circuit is a constant current sink for the LEDs.

Comment: _"The led rating is about 1.2 to 3.6 V for Vf and 10 to 30 mA for current rating. Just noticed my wrong connection. Thanks for mention."_ Please update your question. Comments can and may be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 3):

The schematic of the constant current sink circuit is correct.
Calculating resistances is simple.
[image: current sink]

Comment: beat me to it...

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the value of resistor for R1 and R2?

Start with value for R2. That's the current sense resistor. It should drop about 1 diode drop (0.6-0.7V) at the current you want. So you only need Ohm's law for that.

Then R1 needs to be sized to provide enough base current for the worst-case (lowest) hfe on Q2.

Q2's C-E voltage is rather high, even if the LEDs were dropping 5V each. So a low hfe won't be a problem with any transistor you choose. Assuming hfe(min)=30 or 50 should be a good starting point.

> The hfe for this transistor is 120

That's some typical value, not much help in the design of this particular circuit.

Depending on the hfe of a transistor is perilous - it can be in a wide range. The circuit should still work across a wide range of hfes. This one should work from some minimum hfe - the presumed worst case for the Q2 transistor - up to "infinity" hfe.